# 配列のパラメータのdidSetについて

Tags: swift

```
var test: [NSNumber] = [] {
    didSet {
        // ログ出す
    }
}
```

上記の場合、testの配列を書き換えるとdidSetが呼ばれることは確認できたのですが
どの配列が書き換わったのかはdidSetではわからないのでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didSet`内では変更前の値を示す`oldValue`という名前のパラメータが利用できます。
その値と現在の値（例では`test`）を比較することで何が変わったのかを判断することができます。

```
var test: [NSNumber] = [] {
    didSet {
        print(oldValue) // 変更前の値
        print(test)     // 現在（変更後）の値
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
この場合、何番目の配列かということはわからないのが正しいのでしょうか。

Comment: それを教えてくれるような機能はありません。古い値と新しい値を比較して自分で調べる必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
そうなのですね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。